# android intent not work for wifi,sound,bluetooth?

Tags: android, android-intent, settings, android-wifi

I'm try to call setting which display WiFi,sound and bluetooth but is not work:
i will put my code here and also logcat i want this settings on button click event and display only selected icons
if any other way to use this

i want to use like see image here[image]

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.wifi);

    Button wifi =(Button)findViewById(R.id.wifi);
    wifi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.AUTHORITY);
            intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_AUTHORITIES, new String[] {                      

                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS
                                });
            intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_AUTHORITIES, new String[] {                      

                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS
                                });
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

> Logcat

```
12-13 10:36:04.229: E/AndroidRuntime(1167): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=authorities cat=[android.settings.BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS,android.settings.SOUND_SETTINGS,android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS] }
12-13 10:36:04.229: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
12-13 10:36:04.229: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
12-13 10:36:04.229: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3217)
12-13 10:36:04.229: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3324)
12-13 10:36:04.229: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at com.example.settings.WifiActivity$1.onClick(WifiActivity.java:30)
12-13 10:36:04.229: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
12-13 10:36:04.229: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14109)
12-13 10:36:04.229: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-13 10:36:04.229: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-13 10:36:04.229: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 10:36:04.229: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-13 10:36:04.229: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 10:36:04.229: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-13 10:36:04.229: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-13 10:36:04.229: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-13 10:36:04.229: E/AndroidRuntime(1167):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the EXTRA_AUTHORITIES like this:

```
intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_AUTHORITIES, new String[] {
    Calendar.AUTHORITY
});
```

and intent.addCategory is not used for this. use only one android.provider.Settings. type per intent.

Comment: i want to open the settings from my apps on buttonclick after that is redirect to settings and display only wifi,bluetooth and sound settings other setting don't want to display is not work for this

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>

Comment: what is written in the logcat?

Comment: you mean like this   Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.EXTRA_AUTHORITIES);
    intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_AUTHORITIES, new String[] {         
      Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS,
      Settings.ACTION_SOUND_SETTINGS,
      Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS
     });
    startActivity(intent);

Comment: no.  Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.EXTRA_AUTHORITIES);  is wrong!

Comment: if you solved this than tell me  how to achive this because this is really urgent for me

Answer (score 1):

It is saying `ActivityNotFound`. So problem must be in this line.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.EXTRA_AUTHORITIES);
```

I think you should try

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: yes i will try this but is show all the option in settings  but my client requirement is user only see three option in setting WIFI,BLUETOOTH AND SOUND other setting hide automatically

Answer (score -2):

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { 
    act=android.settings.WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS 
}

onCreate    XT1706
onCreate    MobileName=XT1706
onCreate    WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS is null
onCreate    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS }
onCreate    XT1706
onCreate    MobileName=XT1706
onCreate    WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS is null
onCreate    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS }
onCreate    XT1706
```